# Inputting Data into Database and reading it

Tags: sql, database, vb.net, sql-server-2014

I have an `SQL` database and 2 VB applications, teacher and student application.

In the teacher application, the `SQL` database is connected with datagridview. In the form there are 10-15 checkboxes. those checkboxes are a set of weak points the teacher can select for a student in their class. for eg- "weak in calculations" etc. I want, when the teacher select the checkboxes, they should be shown in the teacher application in a string form. I think assigning each check box an ID would be a lot better than inputting long strings into the database. when the teacher selects a checkbox, the ID for that checkbox goes into the datagridview selected cell. I am not sure how to seperate each ID in the same cell because the teacher can select multiple checkboxes.

I need help with seperating the IDs and then reading them.

http://www.filedropper.com/sample_18  here is a sample program i made, it shows entering the checkbox id into the datagridview.

Comment: Which RDBMS is this for? Please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Comment: Microsoft SQL server 2014

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's keep it simple. Let's say we have 3 check boxes.

So for saving to db:

```
dim totalValue as integer = 0
if (chkBox1.checked) then totalValue +=1
if (chkBox1.checked) then totalValue +=2
if (chkBox1.checked) then totalValue +=4
```

save to db the totalValue

For reading from db:

```
totalValue = get this value from db
chkBox1.checked = ((totalValue and 1)=1)
chkBox1.checked = ((totalValue and 2)=2)
chkBox1.checked = ((totalValue and 4)=4)
```

Comment: ohk, i get the first bit, but can you explain whats going on in the reading from db? thanks a lot! :D this is very helpful

Comment: Reading from db is that you want to check the correct check boxes, just like teacher did before the save.

Comment: but i dont get how it works.if total value is 10, how would it check for 1, 2 and so on?

Comment: It compare bits on two values. 10 in binary is 1010 and 1 is 0001. So: 1010 and 0001 = 0000 which is different than 0001 so false . In VB code: `Dim b As Boolean = (10 And 1) = 1 ' b = false`